# mysqli_connect fail on localhost of IIS on Windows 7 when executing PHP from a local website

Tags: php, mysql, iis, localhost

I am a control systems engineer who is trying to learn MySQL and PHP for the first time.

My Windows 7 Home Premium developmental computer has MS IIS server installed.  I've used Internet Information Services IIS Manager to create the small 1 page website on my computer in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite`.  The address when browsing the site, is http:\192.168.1.8.

MySQL Server 5.6 is installed in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`. PHP 5.3 is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\V5.3`.  Phpmyadmin 4.0.4 is installed in `C:\inetpub\phpmyadmin`.  I am the only user of my computer and therefore I have administration rights.

I successfully used `"http://localhost/Phpmyadmin"` to create the MySQL database and its first table.  It sees the database at 127 0 0 1.

The following line in my php file, will return the error string (thats progress for me, because the browser doesn't just display the contents of the php file).

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('http : // 127 0 0 1', 'mysqlusername', 'mysqlpassword', 'mydatabase')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
```

The mysqlusername, mysqlpassword and mydatabase all work with http : // localhost/ phpmyadmin.  For the connection, I've tried: `http : // 127 0 0 1`, `http : // localhost`, and `http : // localhost/ 127 0 0 1`.  But I always get the error.

A windows search, shows the database in 2 places: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL Server 5.6 
Data\mydatabase` and at `localhost / 127 0 0 1/ mydatabase`.

Can anyone please help me figure out what is wrong?  Perhaps there is a config file somewhere that needs a change?  Does anyone know if there is a simple guide out there that explains the basics (maybe a map) of how IIS, MySQL and PHP work together.

In the above sentences, I put a bunch of spaces and I changed some periods into spaces so that I could post this question.

Comment: What's the actual error when it tries to connect to the database?  You can use `mysqli_error()` to get the actual error instead of the error you put in your `die()` statement: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 4):

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('http://127.0.0.1', 'mysqlusername', 'mysqlpassword','mydatabase')
```

would not work, it's not connecting via HTTP. Just specify IP or hostname:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'mysqlusername', 'mysqlpassword','mydatabase')
// or
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysqlusername', 'mysqlpassword','mydatabase')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Simply using 127.0.0.1 worked perfectly!  I am having only 1 other problem, MS Expression Web 4 can’t publish to my localhost.  Error: The server extensions were unable to access the file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\_vti_pvt/service.lck.  I configured Expression Web 4 to use: connection type: File System, and location: C:\inetpub\wwwroot. I used Windows Explorer to check the permissions for the inetpub, wwwroot, mysite and _vti_pvt folders, which are all set to CREATER OWNER, the permissions for service.lck is SYSTEM.  Is there an easy solution to this?  Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried to run MS Expression Web 4 with lifted privileges? To do this right-click on your MS Expression Web 4 shortcut and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Good idea.  That worked, I can publish but ..... now when I launch MS Expression Web 4, MS Windows 7 thinks its from an unknown publisher and I get the "User Account Control" dialog box every time.  Also, if I right click my HTML file and choose "Edit with Microsoft Expression Web 4", I'll get the same dialog box and then another that says "There was a problem sending the command to the program.", Expression Web 4 opens, but not the HTML file.